# How to enrich event data in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, event-handling

I have a `Parent.vue`, where i send an object to a `Child` component, and get back the updated item every now and then via `this.$emit('updateItem', item)`.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Child
      v-for="(item, index) in items"
      :key="index"
      :item="item"
      @updateItem="updateItem"
      // @updateItem="updateItem(index, dataFromChildComponent)" // this is what i would like to do
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Parent',

  data() {
    return {
      items: [] // List of objects
    }
  },

  methods: {
    updateItem (index, data) {
      // Receive the data and the index
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The problem i keep running into is how to locate the object in the list of items in the `Parent` to update the correct one. I would like to enrich this data to add e.g. an index to be able to locate the item in the list.
Is there any way to achieve this or is it actually the correct way to propagate the index down to the `Child` in order to emit it back up again? Feels like an anti-pattern to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options to achieve that:

1. You can pass as a props index to child component and then in child emit function send object containing updated index with updated value.
2. You can change your current code to something like this: `@updateItem="updateItem(index, $event)"` where $event is updated value

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not know, i still have access to `$event` in the Parent

Answer (score 1):

Updating your event listener as `@updateItem="data => updateItem(index, data)"` should work. Assuming you have emitted data from child component (i.e. something like `this.$emit('updateItem', somedata)`).